# variable undefined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this project in Angular and I am trying to recover information from a function on another function. This is my code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSessionUser();
  }

  private getSessionUser() {
    this.authService.auth$
    .subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.getForms();
    });
  }

  filterByStatus(estado: EstadoRegistro | null) {
    if (estado){
      this.dataSource.data = this.data.filter(item => item?.lastLog?.ID_ESTADO === estado);
    } else {
      this.dataSource.data = this.data;
    }
  }

  getLogs(formId: string) {
    this.supervisorService.getLogs(formId).subscribe((logs) => {
      this.dataSource.data = logs;
      console.log("historic length: "+logs.length);
      this.oneLog = logs.length
      console.log("onelog: "+this.oneLog.toString())
    });
    
  }

  getForms() {
    this.supervisorService.getForms()
    .subscribe((forms) => {
      this.dataSource.data = forms;
      this.data = forms;
      this.getLogs(forms[0].ID_FORM)
      console.log("forms: "+this.oneLog);
    });
  }
```

I need to work with the historical log, to check the status within it for every single record. But if I try to recover the historical information so I can push what I need to every single object of the form there comes up the undefined label as you can see here:

```
forms: undefined
historic length: 5
onelog: 5
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `this.supervisorService.getLogs(formId)` is async, so `console.log("forms: "+this.oneLog);` is going to print **before** `subscribe((logs) => {` finishes and sets `this.oneLog`

Comment: Also don't do `subscribe` in `subscribe`, that's an anti pattern in RxJs